# How to generate some random but valid data for application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, web-applications, test-data

I want to generate some random data but valid data for my application. The data should be in the valid form such as valid names, valid addresses, valid email id's, so form validation should pass. any data generator tool that can be configured and that should generate some random data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/ which is nice and has a lot of stars on github.

Here is how you generate something basic in the browser

```
<script src = "faker.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  var randomName = faker.name.findName(); // Caitlyn Kerluke
  var randomEmail = faker.internet.email(); // Rusty@arne.info
  var randomCard = faker.helpers.createCard(); // random contact card containing many properties
</script>
```

And here is in nodejs

```
var faker = require('faker');

var randomName = faker.name.findName(); // Rowan Nikolaus
var randomEmail = faker.internet.email(); // Kassandra.Haley@erich.biz
var randomCard = faker.helpers.createCard(); // random contact card containing many properties
```

If you want to generate data in the database you could write some seeding scripts (and use this to generate some random but controlled data).

Answer (score 1):

Here is something if u want to test your desired output in JSON format.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dyson#installation

We can specify the output that we want to get when we make API call